# Printing out individual QPs

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades2
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    
    int NUMBER_OF_COURSES = 5;
    int totalQualityPoints;
    double GPA; // Grade Point Average
    int QP = 0; // only need to store quality points
    String courseGrade;
    int[] courseNumber ={5};
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
    
    for (int n = 1; n<=5; n++) 
    {
      System.out.print( "Enter Class "+n+" grade : " );
      courseGrade = in.next();
      
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "A" ) )
      {
        System.out.println( "Outstanding" );
        QP += 4;
      }
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "B" ) )
      {
        System.out.println( "Above average" );
        QP += 3;
      }
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "C" ) )
      {
        System.out.println( "Average" );
        QP += 2;
      }
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "D" ) )
      {
        System.out.println( "Below average" );
        QP += 1;
      }
      if ( courseGrade.equals( "F" ) )
      {
        System.out.println( "Try again" );
        QP += 0;
      }
    }
    
   
  }
}
```

How would I output the individual course QPs into a form like this

```
Course 1 : 9 quality points(s) (QP[1])
Course 2 : 9 quality points(s) (QP[2])
Course 3 : 9 quality points(s) (QP[3])
Course 4 : 9 quality points(s) (QP[4])
Course 5 : 9 quality points(s) (QP[5])
```

I think adding something next to the QPs and associate them with something but I'm not sure how to do so. I tried adding something next to it and I'm not sure how so I always end up with int found array needed. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: hello welcome to SO, by the code you provided you need to store QP as an array if you need to store different quality points for each course hence the desired output would be possible

Comment: I missed a couple classes and now I'm kinda behind. Not really sure how to do that, could you maybe provide an example?

Comment: I tried googling and watching some youtube videos aswell but that'd didn't help very much for me